# JSON Jackson, how to use read only property alias for backwards compatibilty?

Tags: java, json, jackson

We have a structure that represents configuration of some sort. We have had a typo in the word *periodicity*, it was wrongly spelled with 'o' as *period*o*city*. Below example source is the corrected one. However, I need to be able to read the old configuration files to maintain backwards compatibility.

**Can I make JSON Jackson recognize the misspelled field/property on deserialization but ignore it on serialization?**

We are using version 2.6.6 of JSON Jackson.

```
package foo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Rule {
    private LogPeriodicity periodicityLevel;
    private Integer periodicity;

    // ctors and some other methods omitted for brevity

    public LogPeriodicity getPeriodicityLevel() {
        return periodicityLevel;
    }

    public void setPeriodicityLevel(LogPeriodicity periodicityLevel) {
        this.periodicityLevel = periodicityLevel;
    }

    public Integer getPeriodicity() {
        return periodicity;
    }

    public void setPeriodicity(Integer periodicity) {
        this.periodicity = periodicity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got your question right you want something like this?

```
MyClass obj =  mapper.readValue("{ \"name\" : \"value\"}", MyClass.class);
String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);

MyClass obj2 =  mapper.readValue("{ \"name2\" : \"value\"}", MyClass.class);
String serialized2 = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj2);

if( Objects.equals(serialized2, serialized))
    System.out.println("Success " + serialized + " == " + serialized2 );
```

if you don't want extra field in POJO you can just add setter like this:

```
public static class MyClass {
    @JsonProperty
    private String name = null;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonSetter
    public void setName2(String name2) {
        setName(name2);
    }
}
```

You can probably also register legacy Mixin instead of `@JsonSetter`

```
public abstract class  LegacyMyClassMixIn{
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonGetter("name")
    public abstract String getName();
    @JsonSetter("name2")
    public abstract void setName(String name) ;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.setMixInAnnotation(MyClass.class, LegacyMyClassMixIn.class);
mapper2.registerModule(module);
```

*Btw in Gson it can be done with just 1 line `@SerializedName(value="name", alternate={"name2"}) public String name = null;`*

Comment: I have used the `@JsonSetter` annotation on the misspelled setter and it works fine for me. Thank you!